# Combining 2 files of ints in ascending order, comparing them, and then sorting them into a 3rd file without using arrays in c

Tags: c, file, sorting, input, output

Im trying to read in 2 .txt files containing integers sorted in ascending order into a third and I  cannot use arrays. It works partially and then prints an infinite amount of squares. I believe this is an issue when the code gets to the end of one of the files.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
int main() 
{
    FILE *n1, *n2, *op;
    int c, d;
    n1 = fopen("numbers1.txt", "r");
    n2 = fopen("numbers2.txt", "r");
    op = fopen("output.txt", "w");
    c = fgetc(n1);
    d = fgetc(n2);
    while (1 )
    {

        if (c == EOF && d == EOF)
            break;
        else if (c<d )
        {
            putc(c, op);
            c = fgetc(n1);
        }
        else if(d<c )
        {
            putc(d,op);
            d = fgetc(n2);
        }
        else if(d == c )
        {
            putc(c, op);
            c = fgetc(n1);
        }
        else if (c == EOF && d != EOF )
        {
            putc(d,op);
            d = fgetc(n2);
        }
        else if (c != EOF && d == EOF )
        {
            putc(c, op);
            c = fgetc(n1);
        }
    }

    fclose(n1);
    fclose(n2);
    fclose(op);
}
```

Comment: Have you used a debugger to trace the execution of your program? [How to debug small programs?](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)

Comment: `c != '\0'`. Text files never contain the NUL character.

Comment: yes it does it partially then sets one of the values to -1

Comment: @kaylum I figured that. I was browsing for a solution and put it just in case i can remove it

Comment: "just in case" is not a good guiding principle for programming. Either you know you need it or you know you don't. If you are unsure then do research to be sure. Putting in "just in case" code can be harmful.

Comment: `if (c == EOF && d == EOF)` That condition is wrong. What happens if one file has less numbers than the other? It means one of `c` or `d` will then be the `EOF` value for the code below which is doing comparisons.

Comment: @kaylum that's why i have the 2 cases where 1 is EOF and the other isint.

Comment: But you have this: `else if (c<d && c != '\0')` **before** those other `EOF` checks. That is, you are using `EOF` as a valid number in some of your comparisons.

Comment: I edited it to my original code. What is happening is when one file is at EOF it is not stopping. one files max number is 10 while the other is 13 so when that 10 is added to the output file and it goes to the next compare, it is not receiving a correct value

Comment: But that's exactly what I'm telling you. `if (c == EOF && d == EOF)` is wrong and causes the behaviour you are seeing.

Comment: @kaylum I removed it. However the same error is still occuring. How could   I go about fixing it.

Comment: When one of the file reaches EOF you need to stop comparing and just transfer each remaining number from the other file to the output file.

Comment: @kaylum tis may be a stupid question but how?

Comment: BTW Are your _integers_ one digit ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void){
    FILE *n1, *n2, *op;
    int st1, st2;
    int c, d;
    n1 = fopen("numbers1.txt", "r");
    n2 = fopen("numbers2.txt", "r");
    op = fopen("output.txt", "w");

    st1 = fscanf(n1, "%d", &c);
    st2 = fscanf(n2, "%d", &d);
    while(1){
        if(st1 == EOF && st2 == EOF)
            break;
        if(st1 != EOF && st2 != EOF){
            if(c < d){
                fprintf(op, "%d\n", c);
                st1 = fscanf(n1, "%d", &c);
            } else if(c > d){
                fprintf(op, "%d\n", d);
                st2 = fscanf(n2, "%d", &d);
            } else {
                fprintf(op, "%d\n%d\n", c, d);
                st1 = fscanf(n1, "%d", &c);
                st2 = fscanf(n2, "%d", &d);
            }
        } else if(st1 != EOF){
            fprintf(op, "%d\n", c);
            st1 = fscanf(n1, "%d", &c);
        } else {
            fprintf(op, "%d\n", d);
            st2 = fscanf(n2, "%d", &d);
        }
    }
    fclose(n1);
    fclose(n2);
    fclose(op);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The cleanest way to do this is to write three separate loops:

```
// Do the main loop until you reach the end of one of the files
while (!(c == EOF && d == EOF))
{
    // do your stuff here
}

// At this point, at least one of the files is at EOF.
// You want to drain the other
// Note that only one of the two loops will be entered.
while (c != EOF)
{
    // copy the remaining contents of the first file to the output
}
while (d != EOF)
{
    // copy the remaining contents of the second file to the output
}
```

I know, it looks like more code. But you don't have all those `if` statements in the loop checking to see if you're at the end of the first file but not at the end of the other, etc. The above is a whole lot easier to understand, and you're more likely to get it right when you create it.